# Trouble fitting an ODE model using deSolve and Approxfun(), converging to initial guess

Tags: r, function, parameters, ode, forcing

I am trying to fit an ODE model using deSolve to extract a parameter value, alpha. I have data on two species from a pairwise experiment and I want to get the interaction strength of one species on the second. I am using a forcing function, approxfun(), to interpolate the time series of the second species and passing it into the model. My issue is that the parameter value I keep getting is the same as my initial guess.

```
t <- c(0,4,5,7,10,12,14,17,19,21,24,26,28,31,33,35,38,40)
N1 = c(4.000000,772.727273,4139.175258,3585.635359,22.909507, 0.000000,
       148.936170,45.454545,4.95049,35.353535,131.979695,46.082949,
       61.452514,87.804878,155.778895,80.000000,76.081788,120.418848)
N2 = c(0.00000,0.00000,0.00000,20.61856,97.36541,109.43912,195.74468,
       227.27273,69.30693,116.16162,157.36041,153.60983,195.53073,82.92683,
       50.25126,20.00000,19.02045,109.94764)

N2data <- as.data.frame(list(t, N2))
InterpN2 <- approxfun(N2data, method = "constant", rule = 2)

parms <- c(alpha = 0.9)

state = c(N1 = BTdataT$final.dens[1])
r = 1.5
K = 7000


logistic <- function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state,parameters)),{

    dNdt = r*N1*(1-(N1/K))-(alpha*N1*InterpN2(t)) 

    list(c(dNdt), InterpN2(t)) 
   }) 
 }

Out <- ode(times = t, func = logistic, y = state, parms = parms)
plot(Out)

 y.obs  <- BTdataT$final.dens

 shootfun <- function(alpha){
  Out <- ode(times = times, func = logistic, y = state, parms = parms)

  y.pred <- Out[,2] 

  sigma  <- sqrt(sum((y.obs-y.pred)^2)/length(y.obs))

  nloglike <- -sum(dnorm(y.obs, mean = y.pred, sd = sigma, log = TRUE))
  return(nloglike)
}

shoot <- mle2(shootfun,start=list(alpha = parms[1]),
              method="Nelder-Mead")
summary(shoot)
```

My expected results would be an actual alpha value extracted from this data, and not one that converges to the initial condition. I am new to this and currently not understanding it very well. Thank you so much for helping!!

Comment: This code makes no sense. The logistic equation is a one-dimensional equation. Why has the derivative value two components? And you are expecting the output to also have two-dimensional states, and you take the second one which intuitively would be the cumulative sum of the `N2` entries, while the first contains the numerical `N1` values...

Comment: Start slowly. Does the simulation of an instance with fixed parameters work? Do the results appear where you expected them to appear? Does a plot of the result look right? If you add a slight variation to the parameters, and sample them at the same points as the inputs, does the distance between the two integration results reflect the distance in the parameters? And so on with debugging and testing.